# Simple-ish probability question

Tags: probability

A satellite system consists of 4 components and the system can function if at
least 2 components are working. If each component independently works with probability
0.8, what is the probability the system will function?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: Work out the probability that all 4 are broken, and the probability that precisely 3 are broken, then subtract both of those from 1 to give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system will not work, if 3 or 4 components are not working. We can calculate the probability for that:

$P($all components are broken$) = 0.2^4 = 0.0016$

$P($3 components are broken$) = {4 \choose 3} \cdot 0.2^3 \cdot 0.8^1 = 0.0256$

So the chance that the system is not running is $0.0016 + 0.0256 = 0.0272$. Therefore the chance that the system is running is $1-0.0272 = 0.9728$.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, can't believe I didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

It is the chance that 2of4 OR 3of4 OR 4of4 components function:

${4 \choose 2}(4/5)^2(1/5)^2 + {4 \choose 3}(4/5)^3(1/5)^1 + {4 \choose 4}(4/5)^4(1/5)^0 = 0.9728$

notice the use of $P_{M;n}= {n \choose m}P^m(1-P)^{n-m}$

Similarly, it is $1-$(the chance that 3of4 OR 4of4 components do not function):

$1-({4 \choose 3}(1/5)^3(4/5))+ {4 \choose 4}(1/5)^4 = 1-0.0272 = 0.9728$